# Spring mvc resources can't be accessed or are not working

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-mvc

From one moment to another project my spring mvc stopped using the CSS files and JavaScript and is only showing pure html.

Yesterday was still working ok with the project and now the layout files do not work.

Was using hardcoded links in html, I tried to change to use this way and also is not working.
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

I'm using spring tools suite.

Anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, I ended up using a previous version of git and copying all the files I had edited for the old version, and for some reason is working.

Edit: In fact the only thing that happened is that when I was testing the old design google chrome stored the layout files in the cache, I had a poorly mapped url, making any request for layout files returned null